# Make a variable work inside a square bracket while working with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, variables, xpath, f-string

I'm working scraping a page, and I can't remember how to do it for make a variable work inside a string who is working with selenium inside another variable

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

len_trs_table=6
for i in range(0,int(len_trs_table)):
        tr = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[5]/div[8]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/fieldset/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/fieldset/div/div[6]/table/tbody/tr[{i}]')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*`len_trs_table`* is of type *`integer`*. So while passing passing it to the *xpath* for variable substitution you have to convert it into a *`string`* type using either of the following strategies:

- Using *f-string*:

  ```
  len_trs_table=6
  for i in range(0,int(len_trs_table)):
      tr = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'/html/body/div[5]/div[8]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/fieldset/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/fieldset/div/div[6]/table/tbody/tr[{str(i)}]')
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You Have to use f-string

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

len_trs_table=6
for i in range(0,int(len_trs_table)):
        tr = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,f'/html/body/div[5]/div[8]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/fieldset/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/fieldset/div/div[6]/table/tbody/tr[{i}]')
```

As shown in Above code you have to just writ **f** before your str(xpath)

If my answer helps you [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) my answer and also upvote